# PHP filename/path is invalid despite existing

Tags: php, html

So i'm trying to do a simple image upload, the current situation however is that the script will run and return that the filename/path is invalid, despite it 110% existing...

PHP Code (This currently has an unused function called StartPY but i do not believe this is the error):

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

function StartPy(){
    $command_exec = escapeshellcmd('A:\OCR EXPERIMENT\main.py');
    $str_output = shell_exec($command_exec);
    echo $str_output;
}


try {
   
    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['fileToUpload']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo "File is uploaded successfully. \n";
    echo "Running Python Backend now!";
    StartPy();
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

And the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently i am using PHP 7.3.12 on WAMP 3.2.0.

The exact error:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: finfo::file(): Empty filename or path in E:\wamp64\www\www\upload.php on line <i>40</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>410208</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\www\upload.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\upload.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>411040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/finfo.file' target='_new'>file</a>
(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp64\www\www\upload.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\upload.php<b>:</b>40</td></tr>
</table></font>
Invalid file format.
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting, since none of the exceptions are returning anything about an invalid path/filename?

Comment: _"This currently has an unused function called StartPY"_ - It's not unused. It's called right after you echo _"Running Python Backend now!"_. It also echoes the result of the python script.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Shouldn't be your slashes in `'A:\OCR EXPERIMENT\main.py'` like that `'A:/OCR EXPERIMENT/main.py'`?

Comment: Or the space between `OCR EXPERIMENT` may be a problem?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'll edit in the exact error word for word

Comment: Also concerning the 'unused' function, sorry for the incorrect wording, it would be more accurate to say that currently it does not effect how the script produces errors even when commented out fully.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES)` and check if it looks correct. It could be that `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']` contains something other than OK or NO_FILE, which your code currently don't handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a configuration error with my server, for some reason upon deleting and then re-writing php.ini it fixed itself, for anyone in the future make sure to set
the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.